# Reorder JSON objects array by specific key

Tags: json, vue.js, ecmascript-6, nuxt.js

I use Nuxt.js (Vuejs 2)

It's my data:

```
nodes: {},
models: [
        { id: 1, name: "samsung", node: 1, price: 56 },
        { id: 1, name: "samsung", node: 2, price: 68 },
        { id: 2, name: "nokia", node: 2, price: 45 },
        { id: 2, name: "nokia", node: 3, price: 49 }
      ]
```

I want the `nodes` variable to be like this:

```
nodes: {
        1: [
            { id: 1, name: "samsung", price: 56 }
        ],
        2: [
          { id: 1, name: "samsung", price: 68 },
          { id: 2, name: "nokia", price: 45 }
        ],
        3: [
            { id: 2, name: "nokia", price: 49 }
            ]
      }
```

In fact, I want the models array to be converted and separated by `node` key.
How can I  do that? (ES6 prefered)

Comment: You shouldn't do that. Arrays are faster than objects in JS. Transforming your array into an object just so you could access it by its id is not the way to go. You should just use a `findById(id) { return this.nodes.find(n => n.id === id)}` function to get the items. You can also sort the array by ids, if that's what you need. Not to mention the confusion from the fact you're setting  `models[0]` as `nodes[1]`, `models[1]` as `nodes[2]` and so on...

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

```
transformModels(models) {
  const transformedModels = {};

  models.forEach(model => {
    if(!transformedModels[model.node]) {
         transformedModels[model.node] = []; 
    }
    transformedModels[model.node].push(model);
  });

  return transformedModels;
}

nodes = transformModels(models);
```